# MySQL Group Join Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have below three SQL statement and I want to select out like below, I tried but not success.

Need some 
help.

Output:

```
member_id, balance, firstname, lastname, LastPurchase, LastOrde


SELECT c.member_id
     , c.firstname
     , c.lastname
     , m.balance 
  FROM member m
     , customer c
 where  m.member_id =  c.member_id
 order 
    by m.member_id


SELECT member_id, max(date) as LastPurchase 
  FROM purchase
 GROUP 
    BY member_id

SELECT member_id, max(date) as LastOrder   
  FROM ordert
 GROUP 
    BY member_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join these statements -

```
SELECT c.member_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, m.balance, p.LastPurchase, o.LastOrder   
FROM member m
join customer c on m.member_id =  c.member_id
left join (SELECT member_id, max(date) as LastPurchase 
      FROM purchase
      GROUP BY member_id) p on p.member_id = m.member_id
left join (SELECT member_id, max(date) as LastOrder   
      FROM ordert
      GROUP BY member_id) o on o.member_id = m.member_id
order by m.member_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the aggregate queries. The `JOIN ... USING` syntax comes handy here, since all join column names are the same:

```
SELECT c.member_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, m.balance, p.last_purchase, o.last_purchase
FROM member m
INNER JOIN customer c USING(member_id)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT member_id, max(date) last_purchase FROM purchase GROUP BY member_id
) p USING(member_id)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT member_id, max(date) last_order FROM order GROUP BY member_id
) o USING(member_id)
ORDER BY c.member_id
```

**Important**: your original query uses implicit, old-shool joins (with a comma in the `from` clause) - this syntax fell out of favor more than 20 years ago and its use is discourage, since it is harder to write, read, and understand.

One of the many benefits of using explicit joins here is that you can easily change the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s if there is a possibility that a member has no purchase or no order at all.

Comment: Thanks but how to fix the member has no purchase or order? I tried your script but the result missing for these members.

Comment: @WorkingGuy: just change the `INNER JOIN`s on the aggregate queries to `LEFT JOIN`s.